# How to update the UI button text from server side execution in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am using Login control like below,

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="default.aspx" OnAuthenticate="Login1_Authenticate"  RenderOuterTable="false">
  <LayoutTemplate>
    <asp:Literal ID="FailureText" runat="server" EnableViewState="False"></asp:Literal>
    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" name="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Username"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:TextBox ID="Password"  runat="server" TextMode="Password" CssClass="form-control" placeholder="Password"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In &nbsp;&nbsp;" />
  </LayoutTemplate>
</asp:Login>
```

On authentication we need change login button text and redirect to default.aspx page.I tried with RegisterStartupScript and threading both didnt work for me.Please let me know if you have any suggestions for updating UI button text from Login1_Authenticate event.

Comment: when do you want to change the text of button ? while its authenticating ?

Comment: there are two functionalities are there one it will authenticate and after some time it will redirect. once authenticated we need to   update the button text present in the ui. i have tried updating the button text but it will not reflect untill the excecution ends.

Comment: @akshaybogar Either way, you are redirecting user to another page after **Login** button is clicked. ***Changing button Text is too late; user won't see the new button text anyway.*** What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to redirect the user to a specific page based on user's role?

Comment: actually its the customer requirement we tried to convince but client wants in that way

Comment: the time you update the `button` soon after the user will be redirected to next page. How will he/she see the change ?

Comment: I can put thread.sleep(5000) for 5 sec for that period it should show the Success messgae and login to default.aspx page.Which is not happening.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me:

Add this event : OnLoggedIn="Login1_LoggedIn" and on codebehind :

```
 protected void Login1_LoggedIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("www.");

    //OR

    var btn = ((System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)(Login1.FindControl("LoginButton")));
    if (btn != null)
        btn.Text = "REDIRECT";
}
```

Or do the same on Login1_Authenticate event.

Comment: I tried setting the UI button text in Login1_Logged event. as i am trying to redirect to other page in OnAuthnetication event it didnt work for me. can we set the UI button text while executing the event before redirecting to other page...?